# Template Prefers Subclass Function as Opposed to More Specialized Inherited Function

Tags: c++

When I use code like this, I seem to get an unexpected result:

```
class Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(int(*fx)(T)) {
        return true;
    }
};
class Sub : public Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(T t) {
        return false;
    }
};

int foo(int a) {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    bool test = Sub() << foo;
    std::cout << "Used " << (test ? "Base" : "Sub") << " class function";
}
```

This code will use the very generic Sub class function rather than the specialized Base class function on GCC 4.6.3 and VS C++ v141.

But what I would expect it to do is something more like this code:

```
class AClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(int(*fx)(T)) {
        return true;
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(T t) {
        return false;
    }
};

int foo(int a) {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    bool test = AClass() << foo;
    std::cout << "Used " << (test ? "Specialized" : "Generic") << " class function";
}
```

This code, on the other hand, will use the specialized function as expected on GCC 4.6.3 and VS C++ v141.

Here are my questions:

- Is this a feature or a bug?
- What is a good approach to keep the multi-class structure but have templates select well across them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is correct for that example.

When C++ encounters the binary operator expression `A << B`, it looks for three sorts of function and function template declarations:

- the functions that would be found by member name lookup for the expression `A.operator<<`
- the functions that would be found by argument-dependent lookup for the expression `operator<<(A, B)`
- a set of dummy declarations to represent the built-in meanings of the operator, such as `int operator<<(int, int);`

The total combined set of functions found this way is run through the overload resolution process to find the best overload.

The issue in your example is that in the first bullet, the result of member name lookup for `Sub().operator<<` only includes the function template in `Sub`, not the other function template in `Base`.  This is the normal "hiding" rule of derived classes: unless otherwise specified, any member of a derived class hides all inherited members with the same name - even if that name is a fancy one like "`operator<<`".

The simple way to get around the hiding is to add a [`using` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition) to "unhide" the inherited member:

```
class Sub : public Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(T t) {
        return false;
    }
    using Base::operator<<; // NOTE
};
```

The [modified example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4be82ed992c31111) then prints "Used Base class function", since now both members are visible for overload resolution, and the `Base::operator<<` template function is more specialized than the `Sub::operator<<` template function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

`Sub::operator <<` hides `Base::operator <<`.
Unhide it with `using`:

```
class Sub : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::operator <<;

    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(T t) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "pull it down" into the `Sub` class by adding

```
using Base::operator<<;
```

into your `Sub` class definition. Otherwise it will be hidden by the sub class overload.

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(int(*fx)(T)) {
        return true;
    }
};
class Sub : public Base
{
public:

    using Base::operator<<;  // <--- ADD THIS HERE


    template <typename T>
    bool operator <<(T t) {
        return false;
    }
};

int foo(int a) {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    bool test = Sub() << foo;
    std::cout << "Used " << (test ? "Base" : "Sub") << " class function";
}
```